# Add specific custom fields to post formats

Tags: custom-field, post-formats

I am trying to find a simple way to customise my wordpress backend and register different custom fields for each post formats. I know this is easy to do with custom post types but is it at all possible to register different custom fields for the post format video than the post format audio for example? I could not find anything in the wordpress codex or on any google search

Want to achieve this via code not a plugin, any ideas as to which functions to hook into?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your options are this:

http://wordpress.org/plugins/advanced-custom-fields/

and this

http://wordpress.org/plugins/types/

Both will allow you to add different custom fields depending on which custom post type you like the field to appear..

(Though I prefer the first one because it is more flexible for me)

Comment: Yes but this is geared towards post types not the built in wordpress post formats?

Comment: you can use it even on the native post formats (post / page) you just select which one to show the fields on..

Comment: ok tested the advanced custom field but seems a bit of an overkill to do what I want, I was wondering how to do this via code so there is no need to mess around in the UI and confuse users

Comment: using the native custom field would mean the user needs to specify the 'exact' field id, thus makes it harder to the user. check the screen options on the top left and you would have a custom field checkbox there.. enable it and you would have the native custom fields in the admin ui

Comment: Actually the best is to just create the fields and conditions and use the export facility of the plugin to generate the php code and then drop it within your theme. Thanks for pointing me in the right direction thought!

Comment: So you actually used ACF then.. yeah it has that function if you don't want your theme to depend on ACF in the future.. glad to help.